# force download microsoft outlook (.msg) file in IE 11 hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

**Objective:**

we want to have a hyperlink `<a href="pathTo/outlookSampleFile.msg">` Download  in IE 11. But it opens the file on the browser itself displaying some special characters. We want force the file to download. It is working fine in Chrome.

**What we tried:**

I tried with both absolute url and relative url inside href. But no luck

`<a href="pathTo/outlookSampleFile.msg">`

```
<a href="http ://domain.com/pathTo/outlookSampleFile.msg">
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

read the last answer in [This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/why-cant-i-save-msg-as-msg-in-ie-11/83d206fa-23f9-413e-9963-a7248d222112)

i guess there is no way to download it with IE .